# Scala top level package object

Tags: scala

**Edited this question to be more clear, see comments below for explanation.**

So this seems kinda obvious to me, but it doesn't seem like it works that way, but if I have a scala package object and it's in the top level of my packages. Say like `com.company` and it's something simple like below

```scala
package com

package object company{
  val something = "Hello world."
}
```

Now it would seem to me that this variable would trickle down and be accessible from it's child packages, but they aren't.

```scala
// 2 Layers down instead of the direct child
package com.company.app

import com.company._

object Model extends App {
  println(something)
}
```

This seems to only work with the import, which is fine, but I was hoping with the package object I could define top level things for the entire package and have it trickle down, but is that not the case? Is there a way for this to work? I appreciate any insight into this.

Comment: What scala version are you using? I was able to compile `com.company.Model` on `2.11.7`  without import

Comment: This works for me (without `import`), as expected…

Comment: Well I am actually another layer down, so my package object is at `com.company` but my actual code is at something like `com.company.model.ClassFile` and that doesn't work. Let me try again and make sure I'm not nuts.

Comment: Yea, one level of trickle down doesn't work for me in eclipse and Scala 2.11.7, I think the answer below is probably correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code posted in your question works as it is without an import. If you want the definitions of all packet objects above your current package to trickle down, you will have to modify the package statement of the classes in subpackages

Package object

```
package com

package object company {
  val something = "Hello world."
}
```

Class in a subpackage com.company.model

```
package com
package company
package model
// package com.company.model would not work here!

object Model extends App {
  println(something)
}
```

This technique is used frequently in the scala library itself. See for example the package statement in [s.c.i.HashSet](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/ad17b552b8f7c3a435ad8de71cd7268f905a1b8d/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/HashSet.scala):

```
package scala
package collection
package immutable
```

Comment: Interesting and not how I'd expect that to be done, but it's good to know it is possible! Is there any insight into why it's implemented in this fashion?

Comment: It's fully explained at http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/package-clauses/packageclauses_0.html